# Custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, viewgroup

i have create my own ViewGroup. Already i add a Widget to the View i get an Error from Eclipse Design Editor (I need a preview for faster/better development).

```
public class MyViewGroup extends LinearLayout {
    public MyViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.addView(new EditText(context));  // The Error Line
    }
...
}
```

With the LayoutParams don´t change anything:

```
this.addView(new Button(mcontext),
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

The main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
 <...MyViewGroup android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_margin="2dip" android:id="@+id/Token01">    </...MyViewGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

I don´t see it on the emulator. If i remove the "Error Line", the Designer get no error. What was my fail or can´t render Eclipse Designer? But why i can´t see it on the Emulator/Device? My destination is create this part with Custom Views and ViewGroup without XML.

I hope you can help me and sorry for my bad english.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, there's no error in the code (as it runs), but the visual editor doesn't render it correctly.
I once had a similar issue (don't exactly remember) and could solve it by changing the visual editor engine to a Honeycomb version.
In order to do that, you first need to install a Honeycomb SDK (API 11 or greater). Then, in visual editor on the right top corner, you can select the SDK it uses. Change to 3.x. Maybe this works also for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Code never run. The Visual Editor Show an Error and den Emulator don´t show the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it works like a charm with Android 2.3.1 and later. It did not work with 2.2 and earlier.

```
public class MyViewGroup extends LinearLayout {
   public MyViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);

      if (isInEditMode()) {
         final EditText editText = new EditText(context);
         editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         addView(editText);
      }
   }
}
```

Also note the usage of isInEditMode().